# Floated divs not sitting flush

Tags: html, css, wordpress, floating, portfolio

I'm trying to get the portfolio images in the work section of my site to sit flush with no spacing. Right now there is around 3px spacing underneath each image. I think its the containing `div.work_thumb` which is causing it but I'm not sure.

I don't want to set specific heights for everything. Is there another way to get these sitting flush with no spacing at the bottom of them?

Comment: Please don't post questions with a link to your site and no code. After you fix your site, the question will become obsolete and won't help future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `style.css` you have this rule (which seems to be a reset):

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{
  font-size:100%;
  font:inherit;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  vertical-align:baseline; //change to top
}
```

Change from `baseline` to `top`